# Convert key names in a collection in laravel

Tags: laravel

I find myself often waning to 'convert' the key names of a model within a collection. For example, I might do something like:

```
    return $objects->map(function($item){
        return [
            'id' => $item->id,
            'label' => $item->name,
            'image' => $item->thumbnail,
        ];
    });
```

Is there a 'better' way to do this in Laravel 9?

Something like

```
return $objects->keyChange(['label' => 'name', 'image' => 'thumbnail'])
```

Answer (score 0):

There's [`mapWithKeys()`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-mapwithkeys) though it doesn't sound like that's what you want.

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to change multiple keys for each item, and in that case I think a regular `map()` reads nicer and is more clean than the contrived example of `keyChange()`, but that's subjective of course.

Comment: Yes that is right. Fair point on readability, it seems like something there would be a specific method for and I would rather use the more concise method if available.